# Storing array data in the database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was trying to store array data in the database, I didn't get the error message and it doesn't store it in the database. Here is my code in the blade file

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('CheckOut')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="container">
        Name: <input type="text" name="costumer_name" value=""/>
        Address: <input type="text" name="costumer_address" value=""/>
        Contact Number <input type="text" name="costumer_number" value=""/>
    </div>
    @foreach ($carts as $cart)
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-details">
                <input type="text" name="product[]" value="{{ $cart->product }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-quantity">
                <input type="number" value="{{ $cart->quantity }}" min="1" name="quantity[]">
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="{{ route('remove', $cart->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove</a>
            </div>
            <div>{{ $cart->subtotal }}</div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <input type="hidden" id="check_out_value" value="CheckOut" readonly/>
    <input type="submit" id= "checked_out_button" class="checkout" Value="Checkout">
</form>
```

I was trying to store the **costumer_name**, **costumer_address**, **costumer_number** together with the data that is in the loop which is the **product[]** and the **quantity[]** with **id** that is *auto increment*.

Here is my code in the controller

```
public function CheckOut(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->costumer_name;
    $address = $request->costumer_adress;
    $number = $request->costumer_number;
    $products = $request->product;
    $quantity = $request->quantity;

    $data=[];
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $data[]=[
            'name'              => $name,
            'address'           => $address,
            'number'            => $number,
            'product'           => $product,
            'quantity'          => $quantity
        ];
    }
    Order::insert($data);
}
```

It gives me the error

> Array to string conversion

Expected output in the database:

| id | name | address | number | product | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | fili city | 093-256-31 | product1 | 100 |
| 2 | John | fili city | 093-256-31 | product2 | 200 |

Comment: `contentType: false` tells jQuery to not send any `Content-Type` header at all, meaning the receiver will not know how to parse the request body. Remove that.

Comment: @CBroe I tried it just now, it's still doesn't store anything.

Comment: Check if the request looks okay in the browser dev tools, and dump what parameters were received on the server side.

Comment: `it's still doesn't store anything`...do some more detailed debugging then, as CBroe says. You need to narrow down the part of the code where things start to not function as you expected. If you make sure the client-side is doing everything you wanted, then you can move onto the server-side, until you find a more specific issue.

Comment: @GelSSy in your JS code there is a *.then* which is a *method* that doesn't depend on any object... It seems like a copy-paste of some code without understanding the context

Comment: @Pippo yes it does, I just erased it to make the code less.

Comment: Have you tested the $request content in the controller? have you tested the return value of the insert?

Comment: @ADyson it now gives me the error of `Array to string conversion` and at this point, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Well you should re-write your code so it doesn't try to output or store an array into a text format. Arrays have no inherent visual representation, so if (for example) you ask PHP to `echo` an array, or try to write it into a string variable, it will fail because it has no idea what you want that text view of the array to look like. If you need to put array data into a text format you need to write code yourself to format it in the way you would like to see it. Also you didn't tell us - which line of your code exactly is throwing that error?

Comment: Did you check whether this is a PHP problem or a MySQL problem?

Comment: @ADyson I figure out where the problem is, it's in the `quantity[]` , when I try to remove the **[]** in the `quantity[]`, the data will be store in the database but the quantity are all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting

> Array to string conversion

is because you're inserting `$quantity` which is an array, but trying to put it into a single text field.

You need to select the item from the quantity array which matches the product you're inserting. If you use `for` loop to loop through products, then you can use the loop counter to easily select the right item from both the product and quantity arrays.

For example:

```
$data=[];
for($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
    $data[]=[
        'name'              => $name,
        'address'           => $address,
        'number'            => $number,
        'product'           => $products[$i],
        'quantity'          => $quantity[$i]
    ];
}
Order::insert($data);
```

Comment: I added more dupe targets that actually demonstrate how to handle a form submission containing a mix of non-repeatable and repeatable fields. How about `Order::insert(array_map(fn($p, $q) => ['name' => $name, 'address' => $address, 'number' => $number, 'product' => $p, 'quantity' => $q], $products, $quantity));`?

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me you're doing mass assignment on Order::insert(). Are all of the fields you are inserting in your Order model $fillable array? [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Your Order model should contain something like this to even insert any data like you are doing it now:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'number', 'product', 'quantity']
```

Otherwise, you will get the current result and nothing will actually get stored in your orders table.

Comment: Yes, all of the fields are $fillable in the model. If don't use foreach in the controller, it will only store the last data in my blade, I want to everything that is shown in my blade file.

Comment: *Insert()* doesn't need *$fillable*, allows multiple record in a single call but dowsn't fills the dates.