# Unable to get row values along with dropdown list

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, mysqli

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Designation</th>
    <th>M a r k  A t t e n d a n c e</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM userdetails");
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['userid']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['designation']; ?></td>
        <td>
                   <select name="brandlist[]" id = "brandlist" class=="col-sm-2">
                   <option value="present">Present</option>
                   <option value="absent">Absent</option>
                   <option value="late">Late</option>
                   <option value="absconding">Absconding</option>
                   <option value="resigned">Resigned</option>
                   <option value="terminated">Terminated</option>
                   </select>
        </td>
         </tr>
        <?php 
} 
}else{ 
?>
            <tr><td colspan="5">No Employees Found...</td></tr>
        <?php } ?>
</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" name = "submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This works all good, I can see rows displayed on screen and I can also select dropdown list and select attendance. Upon selecting submit, Below code runs all good and saves attendance in table.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']));
{
    $attendances = $_POST['brandlist'];
    foreach($attendances as $item)
    {
       $query = "INSERT INTO attendance (attendancemarked) VALUES ('$item')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
        echo "<script language= 'JavaScript'>alert(' . $useriids . ');</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

This entire code works all good. I am able to get data from userdetails table and display the records in row. I have added dropdown list in every row for marking attendance for employees. When I submit, attendance array saves all the attendance marked but userid, username, designation is not getting saved. I want these 3 fields also to get stored in the table attendance.

Comment: Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anything with a `'` in field (such as `don't` or anything like that)  would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string after the `n`.

Comment: Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Comment: `but userid, username, designation is not getting saved`....well those fields aren't mentioned in your `INSERT` statement, and you don't try to retrieve them from $_POST, and in fact they aren't even fields in your form...so why did you imagine that they would be saved? Go and put them as (hidden) fields in your form, then retrieve them from $_POST, then include them into your INSERT query. It's just the same as you already you do with the attendance data itself. That would seem to be the obvious solution. How/where/why are you stuck with that, exactly?

Comment: P.S. Just as an aside... `name="brandlist[]"` for a list of attendance statuses?? This doesn't seem to make sense. As a tip, try to give your variables and fields meaningful names which reflect what they actually represent. It will make reading, understanding and debugging your code a lot easier (both for you, and for others).

Comment: @ADyson May be i mssed the first line of the code. Form has method post because of which as I mentioned, attendance marked gets stored in table on submitting the button. All I want to know is how do I store values of userid, username and designation in table along with attendance marked. As i am unable to get the value, I have removed those fields from insert query.

Comment: `All I want to know is how do I store values of userid, username and designation in table along with attendance marked`....well if you read my comments again, you'll discover that I've told you. The must be part of the form. Think about it...your attendance data is a field in the form, and is then sent to PHP when the form is submitted. So, given that you know this, to get other data sent to PHP what do you think you would do?? As I said, the solution really ought to be fairly obvious if you give it a moment of  serious consideration.

Comment: is this how it should be

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']));
{
    $attendances = $_POST['brandlist'];

    $updateuserid = $_POST['userid'];

    $updateusername = $_POST['username'];
 
 foreach($attendances as $item)
 {
       $query = "INSERT INTO attendance (userid, usename, attendancemarked) VALUES ('$item', '$updateuserid','$updateusername')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
    }
}
?>

Comment: Well 1) as I already mentioned you need to add them **as fields in the form** as well, 2) No, not unless the username and ID is identical for every row (it's unclear if that's the case or not for your data), 3) I've already told you not to write queries like this, so please go fix that first. 4) Why do you need the user ID _and_ the username in this record? It seems redundant. Learn about database normalisation and foreign keys. 5) I'm sure you said you wanted the designation value as well.

Comment: you're incorporating user input into it.  - There is no user input. it will only display rows on the screen and the last dropdown option which is pre-entered where user cannot change the input

Comment: Let me explain you again. I have a userdetails table in which new users are created, from there only for active users attendance will be marked in another table. Now if I only insert - Present, Absent, Late, without userid and username, it will be very diffivcuilt to know whose attenance is what right. Thats the reason, On pressing submit, userid, username, designation along with attendance will be saved in attendance table. Hope i am able to explain this now properly.

Comment: That's still user input. The user selects a value and sends it back to the server. The input comes from the client-side into PHP. And as you should hopefully realise if you're working with web applications, knowledgeable users can change absolutely anything in your page using the browser's Developer Tools, or bypass the browser entirely by using a different HTTP client. So you can't trust _anything_ sent back from the client-side and you _must_ act accordingly by building your SQL queries in a safe and reliable way as per the links I gave you.

Comment: Wherever you learned this bad technique from, please ignore that resource and don't learn from it again

Comment: `without userid and username`... I didn't say you didn't need them. I said you didn't need **both** of them. One of them should be enough to uniquely identify the user in that table. Try to read what I wrote fully and carefully

Comment: So my question is how do i call the userid, value of respective rows along with attendance marked.

Comment: @ADyson Is the sarcasm really called for? You've been here long enough to know that *everyone* learns to write queries like this, and we're constantly teaching them about prepared statements.

Comment: @Barmar do they? It certainly wasn't how I learned. And unless people go back to their teachers, or shun whatever crummy tutiorials they're getting this stuff from, it will never change, and will continue to waste acres of everyone's time (including the people writing the code). So I'll keep pressing the point.

Comment: @JiteshGala `<input type="hidden" name="user[]" value="<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>">`

Comment: `my question is how do i call the userid, value of respective rows`...I told you, put them in hidden fields in the form. Barmar has kindly given you an example, but you can find examples of hidden fields in HTML anywhere you like on the internet. Try it out.

Comment: True Barmar, I learnt entire PHP, HTML by doing google. Did not go to any classroom. But I will take ADyson's words as my learning, Definetly he wants me to learn the right techniques which I will improve on. But at present what is not letting me sleep is - how do I get userid in attendance table. Please help me for that

Comment: Let me try this, I will get back on this 

<input type="hidden" name="user[]" value="<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>"> –

Comment: And now since user[] is an array of users, doing a `foreach` through the item list won't help you find the matching user. Do a `for` loop instead and use the loop counter to help you find matching records from the various input arrays. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77501712/5947043) is an answer I wrote a few days ago on a very similar point to that.

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry, but it did not capture userids in array, instead, in table for userid , it saved array as value.  What changes are required here

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']));
{

    $userids = $_POST['user'];
    $attendances = $_POST['brandlist'];
  foreach($attendances as $item)
 {
       $query = "INSERT INTO attendance (userid, attendancemarked) VALUES ('$userids','$item')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
        echo "<script language= 'JavaScript'>alert(' . $useriids . ');</script>";
    }
}
?>

Comment: But you *need* to capture user IDs in an array, since each row of the form is a different user ID.

Comment: @JiteshGala see my last comment, which addresses exactly this issue

Comment: Cheked for all the possible solutions.... 

Sorry, But I am lost here completely. Just now able to figure our when dropdown list selection is getting saved in table, why not userid when even that is treated as array. what will be the syntax for storing userid value to xxx variable to add in table

Comment: It's not quite clear what you have or haven't tried by now, without seeing your latest code. Anyway it seems you are still getting very confused for some reason, despite the steps laid out above, so I've written a complete code example in the Answers below.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- The values you want are not available as fields in your form, so they are not sent to PHP
- your PHP code doesn't try to read those values from the submitted `$_POST` data
- your SQL code doesn't try to insert those values into the database table
- your SQL code is written in a way which is insecure and unreliable
- there should be no need to store the user ID *and* username in the attendance table. Only the ID should be needed - it's sufficienct by itself to uniquely identify which user the attendance record relates to.
- there is a typo: `if(isset($_POST['submit']));` needs the `;` removing so it doesn't terminate the `if` block early.

The following example fixes these issues.

**Form display:**
In this section I've added user ID and designation as hidden fields, and given the attendance field a more meaningful name

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Designation</th>
    <th>M a r k  A t t e n d a n c e</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM userdetails");
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['userid']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['designation']; ?></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="user[]" value="<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="designation[]" value="<?php echo $row['designation']; ?>">
                   <select name="attendance[]" id = "attendance" class=="col-sm-2">
                   <option value="present">Present</option>
                   <option value="absent">Absent</option>
                   <option value="late">Late</option>
                   <option value="absconding">Absconding</option>
                   <option value="resigned">Resigned</option>
                   <option value="terminated">Terminated</option>
                 </select>
               </td>
         </tr>
        <?php 
} 
}else{ 
?>
            <tr><td colspan="5">No Employees Found...</td></tr>
        <?php } ?>
</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" name = "submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Form processing:** In this part of the code I've added code to read from all the relevant `$_POST` values, changed the loop to a `for` so the loop counter can be used to select the associated values from each of the submitted arrays (there is one for each field), and used prepared statements and parameters to build the query correctly.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $attendances = $_POST['attendance'];
    $userIDs = $_POST['user'];
    $designations = $_POST['designation'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO attendance (attendancemarked, userID, designation) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($attendances); $i++)
    {
        $stmt->execute([$attendances[$i], $userIDs[$i], $designations[$i]);
        echo "Inserted attendance record for ".htmlspecialchars($userIDs[$i])."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting the same errror which I got last evening...

$attendances = $_POST['attendance'];
Warning: Undefined array key "attendance" in on line 92

$userIDs = $_POST['user'];
Warning: Undefined array key "user" in on line 93

$designations = $_POST['designation'];
Warning: Undefined array key "designation" in on line 94

Comment: @JiteshGala that sounds like you didn't implement the changes to the HTML form properly. Or you submitted something to this script from a different form, perhaps

Comment: I cross checked the entire code twice, thrice, and did not find any error or miss in it.  Code is little long to send the entire one. Is there a way to send it to you the entire code so that I can learn where i am going wrong

Comment: If you have a GitHub account you could paste it into a file there, or share in google drive or something. Don't try to paste it into these comments - they're too short and it's not readable.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jiteshgala/da967d7a3c0692cc4fb7482adccb72fc

Comment: Thanks. There is a typo in your code, which was copied to mine. `if(isset($_POST['submit']));` should be `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` (without the `;` at the end). Otherwise it terminates the `if` block early, and the rest of the code in the brackets runs even when it's not a POST, and then causes those warnings. I have updated the answer to correct it.

Comment: I removed ;, but its still the error, Infact, I had already removed that ; before running the code, but while sending, i replaced with the original which you sent, as I had made several changes in it to see different ways to get it done. With your code, removing ; I am getting the below error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::execute() in markattendance.php:100 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in on line 100

Comment: Sorry my mistake, see updated version. prepare() generates a statement, and then you execute the statement.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still in a learning stage. You got to help me on this Please

Comment: ??? Did you use the latest version of the code? I updated it 1 hour ago (as per my previous comment)

Comment: I got it fixed. Below is the code which fixed it.

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO attendance (attendancemarked, userid, designation) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $attendances, $userIDs, $designations);
$stmt->execute([$attendances[$i], $userIDs[$i], $designations[$i]]);
echo "New records created successfully";

Comment: You don't need bind_param() **and** execute with parameters passed in. What was wrong with the example I provided? Unless you have an old version of PHP, you don't need bind_param, you can simply pass the parameters into execute() (as I showed you). It's not clear why you added that. And `$stmt->bind_param("sss", $attendances, $userIDs, $designations); ` makes no sense anyway - you don't want to add the entire arrays as parameters every time. Each execution of the query needs to pass in the next item from each of the arrays - as I showed you!

Comment: Also take note that the prepare() line should be outside the loop (it's more efficient that way) - again see the most recent version of my example.